# Angular Universal With Window Innerwidth

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

Am Using Window.Innerwidth in my Angular Project, Actually code is working, But My problem is when am trying to implement to Angular universal. What and all are i wrote inside this window.innerwidth. its not showing view source.
My Code is like this.

```
hidemobile:any;
hidedesktop:any;

onresize()
  {
    let width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width < 420) {
      this.hidemobile = false;
      this.hidedesktop = true;
    }else{
      this.hidemobile = true;
      this.hidedesktop = false;
    }
  }
```

HTML Code Like this below...

```
<div *ngIf="hidedesktop" class="top_projects_section">
    <h2>TOP Header</h2>
</div>

<div *ngIf="hidemobile" class="top_projects_section">
    <h2>TOP Header</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `window` object with angular universal. You could try using the user agent header from the request to identify the device used by the client

Comment: Thank you for your support. I fixed the issue by using with Angular Universal        ng-toolkit.

Comment: Hello David. Could you please tel us how did you get around getting window properties in angular universal ?

Comment: @Mehdi Either do not call the code that requires to access `window` object, or add `domino` to your `server.ts` file

Comment: ohhhh, domino! that fixed my whole project